# Java: Why can't I insert parameter instead of %s?

Tags: java

I have a structure as this:

```
String xml = "<tag><another_tag>%s</another_tag></tag>"
```

and I pass a parameter to method and try to replace `%s`:

```
String str = String.format(xml, parameter);
```

But I have got previous xml file wrapped as a tag on the place of '%s'. If I set a simple `String`:

```
String str = String.format(xml, "parameter");
```

all works well.

Why does it happen?

Comment: What's the value of `parameter`?

Comment: Could you post code that reproduce problem because it seams to works fine (at least for me).

Comment: what is `String.formate()`?  do you mean `String.format()`?

Comment: Yes, I can. Sorry, I have  code on my workplace and will get access to it only toworrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pshemo says, this works fine:

```java
String xml = "<tag><another_tag>%s</another_tag></tag>";        
String parameter = "abc";
String str = String.format(xml, parameter);
System.out.println(str); // <tag><another_tag>abc</another_tag></tag>
```

Comment: @RomanC OP said in comment that he is using `String parameter = "parameter"` so does it matter if we use `"abc"` instead of `"parameter"`?